# Copying a struct for use on another thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a struct:

```
struct MyData {
    x: i32
}
```

I want to asynchronously start a long operation on this struct.

My first attempt was this:

```
fn foo(&self) { //should return immediately
    std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || { 
        println!("{:?}",self.x); //consider a very long operation
    });
}
```

Clearly the compiler `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements` because `self` may be on the stack frame and thus cannot be guaranteed to exist by the time the operation is running on a different stack frame.

To solve this, I attempted to make a copy of `self` and provide that copy to the new thread:

```
fn foo(&self) { //should return immediately
    let clone = self.clone();
    std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || { 
        println!("{:?}",clone.x); //consider a very long operation
    });
}
```

I think that does not compile because now `clone` is on the stack frame which is similar to before.  I also tried to do the `clone` inside the thread, and that does not compile either, I think for similar reasons.

Then I decided maybe I could use a `channel` to push the copied data into the thread, on the theory that perhaps `channel` can magically move (copy?) stack-allocated data between threads, which is suggested by [this example in the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html#example).  However the compiler cannot infer a lifetime for this either:

```
fn foo(&self) { //should return immediately
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    tx.send(self.clone());
    std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || { 
        println!("{:?}",rx.recv().unwrap().x); //consider a very long operation
    });
}
```

Finally, I decided to just copy my struct onto the heap explicitly, and pass an Arc into the thread.  But not even here can the compiler figure out a lifetime:

```
fn foo(&self) { //should return immediately
    let arc = std::sync::Arc::new(self.clone());
    std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || { 
        println!("{:?}",arc.clone().x); //consider a very long operation
    });
}
```

Okay borrow checker, I give up.  How do I get a copy of `self` onto my new thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue is simply because your structure does not derive the `Clone` trait. You can get your second example to compile and run by adding a `#[derive(Clone)]` before your struct's definition.

What I don't understand in the compiler behaviour here is what `.clone()` function it tried to use here. Your structure indeed did not implement the `Clone` trait so should not by default have a `.clone()` function.

[playpen](http://is.gd/q5YTVL)

You may also want to consider in your function taking `self` *by value*, and let your caller decide whether it should make a clone, or just a move.

Comment: This works for the question as posed, but there are cases where merely implementing Clone doesn't seem to be good enough--[when the type in question is a generic parameter, for example](https://gist.github.com/drewcrawford/c88d478088d8de412dcf)

Comment: @Drew the problem you encounter with generic parameter is, as the compiler tells you, that the lifetime of your reference is too short, and you should just add a 'static lifetime bound as the thread::spawn function requires. This came recently with the changes to Send, which does not imply 'static any more, in order to allow scoped threads (see example below by @Shepmaster).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, you could use [`thread::scoped`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html) and maintain a handle to the thread. This allows the thread to hold a reference, without the need to copy it in:

```
#![feature(old_io,std_misc)]

use std::thread::{self,JoinGuard};
use std::old_io::timer;
use std::time::duration::Duration;

struct MyData {
    x: i32,
}

// returns immediately
impl MyData {
    fn foo(&self) -> JoinGuard<()> { 
        thread::scoped(move || { 
            timer::sleep(Duration::milliseconds(300));
            println!("{:?}", self.x); //consider a very long operation
            timer::sleep(Duration::milliseconds(300));
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d = MyData { x: 42 };
    let _thread = d.foo();
    println!("I'm so fast!");
}
```

Comment: I was confused about why this works at first. Turns out `JoinGuard` has a lifetime parameter and lifetime elision makes it the same as the unnamed lifetime of the `&self` parameter. Which is nice, but comes with a caveat: The borrow lasts until the `JoinGuard` is dropped. One must be aware of this, and it also complicates the calling code more than the other answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method signature is specified by a trait.  I could of course modify it to add a JoinGuard as a return parameter, but the other implementations of this function don't need one...